# Springfox-boot-starter swagger Instant handling

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, swagger, springfox

I have a problem with swagger documentation using SpringBoot with Springfox-boot-starter.

I use ***java.time.Instant*** wrapped in ***java.util.Optional*** in my REST API which works fine:

```
  @GetMapping("/{subscriptionId}/{variableAlias}")
  public PaginatedResultDTO<MonitoredVariableDTO> getReportedVariables(
    @PathVariable String subscriptionId, 
    @PathVariable String variableAlias, 
    Optional<Instant> from, 
    Optional<Instant> to) { ... }
```

But for some reason, Swagger documentation cannot handle the Optional type correctly and seems to handle it through reflection as EpochSeconds and Nano attributes instead of one field:
[image: swagger ui screenshot]

I would like to make swagger expect **from** and **to** instants in ISO format, just like Spring does and how I use it in Insomnia:
[image]

When I tried to remove the Optional wrapper, it seems to work [image]

Is there a way to make this work with the Optional? Thanks for any advice!

Spring boot version:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.4.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath />
</parent>
```

Springfox-boot-starter version

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

We had exactly the same problem that you.
We solved it with this SpringFox configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SpringfoxConfiguration {

    @Value("${api-doc.version}")
    private String apiInfoVersion;

    @Autowired
    private TypeResolver typeResolver;
    @Bean
    public Docket customDocket(){
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .groupName("xxx")
                //Some other code unrelated to this problem
                .alternateTypeRules(
                        // Rule to correctly process Optional<Instant> variables
                        // and generate "type: string, format: date-time", as for Instant variables,
                        // instead of "$ref" : "#/definitions/Instant"
                        AlternateTypeRules.newRule(
                                typeResolver.resolve(Optional.class, Instant.class),
                                typeResolver.resolve(Date.class), 
                                Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE
                        ))
                .genericModelSubstitutes(Optional.class)
                .select()
                //Some more code unrelated to this problem
                .build();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With spring fox the problem is it doesn't use the custom `ObjectMapper` which you have defined as a `Bean`.

`Springfox` creates own `ObjectMapper` using `new` keyword. Hence, any module you register with your custom `ObjectMapper` is pointless for `SpringFox`. However, `Springfox` provides an interface to register modules with it's own `ObjectMapper`.

Create a configuration bean like below in your project and it should work.

```
@Configuration
public class ObjectMapperModuleRegistrar implements JacksonModuleRegistrar {
  @Override
  public void maybeRegisterModule(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
    objectMapper.registerModule(new ParameterNamesModule())
        .registerModule(new Jdk8Module())
        .registerModule(new JavaTimeModule())
        .findAndRegisterModules();
  }
}
```